# How to add two image State for a setImage()

Tags: ios, swift

I've used setImage to describe state of the current image, but i want to use two state at once in a setImage(). So i want to merge two state .Highlighted & .Selected

```
button.setImage(emptyStarImage, forState: .Normal)
button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: .Selected)
button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: .Highlighted)
```

i have these three states , but i want another state like

```
  button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: [.Highlighted, .Selected])
```

this shows an error , how can i do this ?

Comment: You can not do this. You have to set it one by one.

Comment: Yeah but in a press release they used two state in one , that's the reason , (i'm using xcode 6 )

Comment: I think you are asking for pre-release. then this functionality will only be available with Swift 2 and Xcode 7. Currently it is beta version. Golden Master version will release soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using old version of Xcode.

In iOS 9 They are allow to do this way.

Check the following example by the Apple : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html

There is a file called RatingControl.swift

```
for _ in 0..<5 {
    let button = UIButton()

    button.setImage(emptyStarImage, forState: .Normal)
    button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: .Selected)
    button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: [.Highlighted, .Selected])

    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false

    button.addTarget(self, action: "ratingButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    ratingButtons += [button]
    addSubview(button)
}
```

From Xcode 7 and iOS 9 you can do as like you described :

```
button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: [.Highlighted, .Selected])
```